# NavigationController not working ios 7 but works ios 8 and ios 6

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios6, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I have ran into a problem. I have updated my code in my xcode project and now on ios 7 the navigationController no longer is working but on ios 8 and ios 6 everything is fine.

When app starts I initialize the navigationController with the HomeView

```
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
    navigationController  = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

When i try to segue to another View in ios 7 the View segues but there is no navigation bar on the top nor any way to go back.

```
EditProfileController* profile = segue.destinationViewController;
profile.firstName = self.firstName;
```

When i try to push to a View in ios 7 nothing happens

```
ViewController* view = (ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

I have no idea what I have changed in my code that could of caused this problem. The only things i can think back that i changed and could of effected this was:

- Storyboard Constraints
- Screen Orientation
- Push Notification
- Added Google Analytics
- Added Crashlytics and Instabug

But i have no idea where with bug came from. I pulled up an older version of my project everything works fine on that version. So it must of been something I changed. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks guys!